# Paging store does not changed

Tags: extjs4

I am using Reconfigure function to change the columns and data of the 
panel form.

See below the code that I wrote

```
    var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: tmpFields,
        pageSize: itemsPerPage,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: getDataWithPageURL,

        }
    });


     globalStore = newStore.load({
        params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: itemsPerPage
        }
    });

   grid.reconfigure(globalStore, tmpColumns);
```

The code is working,and the data is changed.
But paging and total does show old data.

Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's bug in the reconfigure function .

So I created pagging bar and added again . See code below

```
    var PagingBar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        pageSize: itemsPerPage,
        store: globalStore,
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    });

    grid.removeDocked(grid.getDockedItems()[1]);

    grid.addDocked(PagingBar);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS, `PagingToolbar` is working closely with a given `Store`, and this is the reason why there is no event listener hooked onto the `reconfigure` because `reconfigure` is defined in `Ext.panel.Table`.

Hence, another solution is by rebinding the store when `reconfigure` has been fired, that is:

```
Ext.define('NS.toolbar.Paging', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent();
        me.on('afterrender', function() {
            me.ownerCt.on('reconfigure', function() {
                me.bindStore(me.ownerCt.store || 'ext-empty-store', true);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Read it as, after the `PagingToolbar` has been rendered, we bind a function to the event `reconfigure` so that whenever a `reconfigure` happens, you rebind the store in paging toolbar.

Tested and it works. [Try it out here at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/cANkd/)

Cheers